Configurable Data Validation formula permitting certain characters and field length
I'm looking for an Excel formula that restricts to certain characters and length. It needs to be easily configurable as i need to apply it to specific columns/rows which have different data entry restrictions.
I've scoured many posts and the closest i came across was the below but the results seem very inconsistent during testing (for example this allows me to add a single asterisk which is outside the permitted characters).
=AND(LEN(A4)<=10,ISNUMBER(SUMPRODUCT(SEARCH(MID(A4,ROW(1:30),1),"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_"))))

When i use the above, something weird seems to be going on with which rows this is applying to. I'm not sure if the mid section can be simplified as i don't need to enter a row range if i can simply copy down the cell which automatically amends the cell references.
In simple terms, a formula where i can define a maximum length and a set of characters that i want to restrict data entry to.
Is anyone able to assist me please?
Many thanks.

* is a special character in SEARCH.

Am I right in reading you want to restrict the input to uppercase alpha, numbers and an underscore for 1 to 30 characters long? If applicable to your version of Excel you could use the following formula for your Data Validation rule:
=REGEXTEST(A1,"^[A-Z\d]{1,30}$")


With Find instead of Search and anchoring the rows it should look like this assuming you want to accept lowercase as well as uppercase:
=AND(LEN(A1)<=10,ISNUMBER(SUMPRODUCT(FIND(MID(A1,ROW($1:$10),1),"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_"))))

or using more recent idiom in Excel 365:
=LET(Maxlen,10,AND(LEN(A1)<=Maxlen,ISNUMBER(SUM(FIND(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(Maxlen),1),"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_")))))


A bit verbose variant - if you have Microsoft 365 (in order to use LAMBDA etc.), could you try this:
The main logic is similar to yours and we can use BYROW to iterate over the input, so please enter the following into the first cell with enough empty rows below.
=LAMBDA(input, max_len, valid_string,
    LET(
        to_chars, LAMBDA(text, MID(text, SEQUENCE(1, LEN(text)), 1)),
        valid_chars, to_chars(valid_string),
        is_valid, LAMBDA(input_cell,
            AND(
                LEN(input_cell) <= max_len,
                AND(
                    MAP(
                        to_chars(input_cell),
                        LAMBDA(i, ISNUMBER(XMATCH(i, valid_chars)))
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        result, BYROW(input, is_valid),
        result
    )
)(A1:A3, 10, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_")


